# Can't upload image Django REST

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, file-upload, django-views

I am trying to upload image through django rest framework api but I am not getting the form properly.

**models.py** in my 'core' app:

```
def office_image_file_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = f'{uuid.uuid4()}.{ext}'

    return os.path.join('uploads/office/', filename)

class Office(models.Model):
    # Other fields...
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=office_image_file_path)
```

**serializer.py** in 'office' app:

```
class OfficeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        """Meta class for OfficeSerializer."""

        model = Office
        fields = "__all__"

class OfficeImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for uploading images to recipes"""

    class Meta:
        model = Office
        fields = ('id', 'image')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        extra_kwargs = {'image': {'required': True}}
```

**views.py** in 'office' app:

```
class OfficeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows offices to be viewed or edited if authenticated.
    """
    queryset = Office.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OfficeSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Retrive offices for authenticated users.
        """
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'upload_image':
            return OfficeImageSerializer

        return OfficeSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=True, url_path='upload-image')
    def upload_image(self, request, pk=None):
        office = self.get_object()
        print(request.data)  # Debug: Print the request data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            office,
            data=request.data
        )

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )

        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
```

In Swagger when I try to upload the image via /office/office/{id}/upload-image/, I do not get the "Choose file" button. Instead I get a string($uri) field and I can't execute the file upload. I have already set MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in my **setting.py** file.

I was expecting a form like:

[image]

But got:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileField can be set to binary by adding the following to in settings.py:

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True
}
```

By doing so, the "Choose file" will appear.

Answer (score 1):

An image will not be added to the body of a request, but rather to the request **FILES**:

```
request.FILES.get("NAME_OF_THE_IMAGE")
```

So even if you would do something like this in Postman:
[image: Postman form-data Screenshot]

The image will be added to the FILES part of the request.
Now, NAME_OF_THE_IMAGE isn't really the name of the image you added, but rather the 'key' (look at the screenshot).

Comment: I am not getting the file form in Swagger